# How to avoid "Type mismatch in expression" in ClientDataSet Filter

Tags: delphi, filter, tclientdataset

The erro msg "Type mismatch in expression" appear when I run this code:

```
CDSIndicados.Filtered := False;
CDSIndicados.Filter   := 'EDICOES_ID like ' + QuotedStr(IntToStr(Integer(cxComboBox1.Properties.Items.Objects[cxComboBox1.ItemIndex])));
CDSIndicados.Filtered := True;
```

I know this message may appear when there is an error in the data type of the field. But I could not fix. Was that it?

Comment: If I was debugging this, I'd first check what value is assigned to CDSIndicados.Filter and then I'd start reasoning.

Comment: can't you just trace that error back to dbcommon.pas to get the idea what is the actual reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm suspecting that your `EDICOES_ID` field is an integer value, in which case you don't need to quote it in your filter expression and the `LIKE` operator isn't supported AFAIK. If it is a string field, you do need the quotes and `LIKE` is supported, but you typically want a wildcard in the expression as well. (*LIKE* is only supported for character (string) type fields. For numerics or dates, you need to use the usual comparison operators *>, <, >=, <=, =* or *BETWEEN*.)

Do yourself a favor, too, and declare a local variable, and making sure that there's actually an item selected in the `ComboBox` before trying to access its `Objects`. I've added one both for the `ItemIndex` and for intermediate storage of the typecast `Object` you're retrieving, which makes it much easier to debug if you need to do so.

Here's a solution either way (whether it's an integer field, or a  string that needs quoting).

```
var
  Idx, Value: Integer;
begin
  Idx := ComboBox1.ItemIndex;
  if Idx > -1 then
  begin
    CDSIndicados.Filtered := False;
    Value := Integer(cxComboBox1.Properties.Items.Objects[Idx]);

    // If the field is an integer, you don't need a quoted value,
    // and LIKE isn't supported in the filter.
    CDSIndicados.Filter   := 'EDICOES_ID = ' +  IntToStr(Value);

    // Not relevant here, but LIKE isn't supported for date values
    // either. For those, use something like this
    CDSIndicados.Filter := 'EDICOES_DATE = ' + QuotedStr(DateToStr(Value));

    // or, if the field is string and you want LIKE, you need to
    // quote the value and include a wildcard inside that quoted 
    // string.
    CDSIndicados.Filter := 'EDICOES_ID LIKE ' + QuotedStr(IntToStr(Value) + '%');
    CDSIndicados.Filtered := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm already sure that there is an item selected in the ComboBox.
I made the suggested changes and the problem continues.
Perhaps the data type of the field is wrong somewhere, I'll keep looking for my mistake.

Comment: The problem Ken described here is that you might have used quoted integer value in your filter (by using `QuotedStr`). Integer values don't like that. [+1]

Comment: Yes, I have corrected this error. But the message "Type mismatch in expression" keeps appearing.

Comment: See my edits (and if that doesn't solve your problem, please provide the data type of the `EDICOES_ID` column).

Comment: Now it worked. EDICOES_ID is an integer column. I changed `EDICOES_ID like` to `EDICOES_ID =` and it worked fine. Thank you.