# Delphi type mismatch in expression when try to filter dbgrid

Tags: delphi

Am getting this error when i try to filter `DBGrid` by date with `DateTimePicker` component

> Type mismatch in expression

**Code**

```
procedure TGrupeForm.DateCreatedFilterChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
     if CreatedEditPicker.Date <> Date then
      begin
        ClientDataSet1.Filter := 'Created LIKE '+QuotedStr('%'+DateToStr(CreatedEditPicker.Date)+'%');
        ClientDataSet1.Filtered := True;
      end
      else
        ClientDataSet1.Filtered := False;
end;
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: What Delphi field type is your Created field?

Comment: What data type is the field? (This is turning into a tutorial for you on using databases in Delphi; you really should find one online or in the documentation.) You also cannot possibly be using all of those Delphi versions simultaneously - stop just randomly adding tags because the name is familiar. With Delphi in particular, you only need version specific tags if your question is specifically about features in a single version, and this question contains nothing version specific. I've removed the 4 unnecessary tags.

Comment: Also, you cannot use `LIKE` on anything but character fields; it doesn't work for dates or numbers. For dates and numbers, use >, >=, =, <, <= or BETWEEN.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16781274/62576) to a similar question that explains how to work with the filter property of a TClientDataSet.

Comment: its datetiime type

Comment: @Ivan I recommend you edit the question and add relevant info, like type of new field.

Comment: Then as I said, you can't use LIKE. Please read my last two comments and the post I linked.

Comment: Okay thanks i will check again that!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `LIKE` on anything but character (string) type fields. For numbers and dates, you need to use the normal comparison operators *>, <, >=, <=, =*. This should work for you with your current filter.

```
procedure TGrupeForm.DateCreatedFilterChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CreatedEditPicker.Date <> Date then
  begin
    ClientDataSet1.Filter := 'Created = ' + QuotedStr(DateToStr(CreatedEditPicker.Date));
    ClientDataSet1.Filtered := True;
  end
  else
    ClientDataSet1.Filtered := False;
end;
```

For numeric fields, you do not quote values, and so `QuotedStr` isn't necessary:

```
ClientDataSet1.Filter := 'ID = ' + IntToStr(Value);
```